# How to combine these regex expressions together

Tags: php, regex, laravel, validation, laravel-request

I'm working with Laravel and I have used this custom regular expression for validating user password request:

```
'user_password'=> ['required','min:6','regex:/[a-z]/','regex:/[A-Z]/','regex:/[0-9]/','regex:/[@$!%*#?&]/']
```

Now I needed to combine these separated `regex`s all together but don't know how to do it, so if you know, please let me know.. thx!

Comment: I don't think that contributors are supposed to provide code translation services.  Beyond that, I am confident that we have several duplicates that explain how to use lookaheads to enforce password strength rules.  Given that you have shown no coding attempt at all, I'll assume that you didn't find ANY of the duplicates that I've provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One general way to do this via a single regex would be to use positive lookaheads to assert each requirement:

```
/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[@$!%*#?&]).{6,}$/
```

The above pattern says to match:

```
^                 from the start of the user password
(?=.*[a-z])       at least one lowercase letter
(?=.*[A-Z])       at least one uppercase letter
(?=.*[0-9])       at least one digit
(?=.*[@$!%*#?&])  at least one special character
.{6,}             then match any 6 or more characters
$                 end of the password
```